# Considerations about Quartz.NET hosted inside scaled out instance of Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, quartz.net

How to handle Quartz configuration for an API which is created in ASP.NET Core and hosted in Azure App Service which is scaled out to more than one instances?

The API currently is always hosted in a single IIS application thus Quartz configuration looks like follow, no cluster configuration used

```
private static NameValueCollection SchedulerConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var schedulerConfiguration = new NameValueCollection();
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = configuration["ConnectionString"];
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer";
    schedulerConfiguration["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json";
    return schedulerConfiguration;
}
```

and it's utilizing `QuartzHostedService` for handling scheduled background jobs

`services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();`

I did a small experiment and deployed the API into the Azure App Service instance, then created a single Quartz job within the API and scaled out a number of instances to 4 before the trigger fired.
My assumption was, that without doing any changes to the above configuration job will be executed 4 times because when the new 3 instances kicked in, all of them would read job details from DB and register triggers to fire at a certain time. But to my surprise, the job was executed only once.

1. Any ideas why the job was executed only once?
2. Should I leverage cluster configuration when hosting Quartz scheduler inside scaled out Azure App Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think that might be just pure luck, if your jobs run fast they might be run only by single instance in the cluster. But without clustered setup two nodes could take same job to run and cause conflicting database updates.
2. Yes, there's slight performance penalty when database based locks are in use, but that's the only way you can run busy instance safely.

I would also suggest that you look into the [ASP.NET Core integration package](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html). It helps with compile-safe configuration, I can for example see that you're now using wrong (inefficient) delegate for SQL Server, there's separate SqlServerDelegate.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and the answer. I configured cluster and all seems to be working fine, I just had to use `SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE SCHED_NAME = @schedulerName AND LOCK_NAME = @lockName` query for `quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL` otherwise I was getting lock errors from Azure SQL. Thansk for pointing out `SqlServerDelegate` 